# regular express with (?:) for grouping and $ at the end

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the regular express

```
(?P<month>[1-9]|1[012])/(?P<day>([0-2])?[1-9]|3[01])/(?P<year>([0-2]\d)*\d\d)
```

It suppose to filter out:

```
Match: 1/1/2000, 1/1/00, 1/01/00, 1/31/00, 2/31/2000, 1/1/0000 

Not Match: 05/1/00, 13/1/00, 2/005/00, 1/32/00, 1/1/200, 1/1/20000, 5/0/2000
```

I got all the match, but somehow the non-match keep get in the way with

```
"5/1/00" "3/1/00" "1/1/20" "1/1/2000"
```

How do I grouping them correctly? I figure out to use (?:) and $ at the end but still stuck somehow? Any help is appreciated.

I try my code at pythex.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression matches substrings too; you'll need to add start and end anchors.

If you are matching whole strings only, use:

```
^(?P<month>[1-9]|1[012])/(?P<day>([0-2])?[1-9]|3[01])/(?P<year>([0-2]\d)*\d\d)$
```

otherwise, use negative look-arounds:

```
(?<!\d)(?P<month>[1-9]|1[012])/(?P<day>([0-2])?[1-9]|3[01])/(?P<year>([0-2]\d)*\d\d)(?!\d)
```

where the `(?<!\d)` prevents your pattern from matching if there is a digit preceding the text being matched, and `(?!\d)` prevents the pattern from matching if there is digit following the text.

[Pythex demonstration](https://pythex.org/?regex=%28%3F%3C!%5Cd%29%28%3FP%3Cmonth%3E%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B012%5D%29%2F%28%3FP%3Cday%3E%28%5B0-2%5D%29%3F%5B1-9%5D%7C3%5B01%5D%29%2F%28%3FP%3Cyear%3E%28%5B0-2%5D%5Cd%29%2a%5Cd%5Cd%29%28%3F!%5Cd%29&test_string=Match%3A%201%2F1%2F2000%2C%201%2F1%2F00%2C%201%2F01%2F00%2C%201%2F31%2F00%2C%202%2F31%2F2000%2C%201%2F1%2F0000%20%0ANot%20Match%3A%2005%2F1%2F00%2C%2013%2F1%2F00%2C%202%2F005%2F00%2C%201%2F32%2F00%2C%201%2F1%2F200%2C%201%2F1%2F20000%2C%205%2F0%2F2000%20%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) using the latter form.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> dates = re.compile(r'(?<!\d)(?P<month>[1-9]|1[012])/(?P<day>([0-2])?[1-9]|3[01])/(?P<year>([0-2]\d)*\d\d)(?!\d)')
>>> dates.findall('Match: 1/1/2000, 1/1/00, 1/01/00, 1/31/00, 2/31/2000, 1/1/0000')
[('1', '1', '', '2000', '20'), ('1', '1', '', '00', ''), ('1', '01', '0', '00', ''), ('1', '31', '', '00', ''), ('2', '31', '', '2000', '20'), ('1', '1', '', '0000', '00')]
>>> dates.findall('Not Match: 05/1/00, 13/1/00, 2/005/00, 1/32/00, 1/1/200, 1/1/20000, 5/0/2000 ')
[]
```

Comment: I try to use ^ $ but python report no match ?!

Comment: @TrungNguyen: then perhaps your dates are found in a longer string? `^` only matches at the *start* of a string, so `"1/1/2000"` works, but `"foo: 1/1/2000"` won't.

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundary like this:

```
\b(?P<month>[1-9]|1[012])/(?P<day>([0-2])?[1-9]|3[01])/(?P<year>([0-2]\d)*\d\d)\b
```